# Value/Placeholder - different styling for words

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, placeholder

I'm having problem with placeholders.
I want to ask, is there possibility to style value in input fields but in the way to style words of that value different.

For example, if we have input field which have initial value `"First Name"` i want to have `green color` for `"First"`, and `red color` for `"Name"` (this is just an example).

Is this even possible?

Note: Im using value as "placeholder" (instead of placeholder html attribute) because of ie.

```
<input type="text" value="First Name" onFocus="if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}" />
```

Comment: I have seen large workarounds for the effect u desire. Basically the input box would be at the top layer, with the text using a transparent font (all blank), after which the textarea behind it would be filled with the custom syntax which is updated on value change via javaScript. It is quite a workaround, and it does not work in iOS (if i recall correctly)... Alternatively u could get a rich text editor, but that might be an overkill for something like a user name input.

Comment: I have several input fields for this form, so i will probabbly use one styling again (that is best solution for something like this, as i can see)  :)...Thank you

Comment: You can always have differant styles for first and last name fields =P And welcome to stackoverflow, feel free to ask around and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately its not possible. when it comes to styling the form elements, there are many hindrances, color can be set to for an element not chracters, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgd2e/1/

Comment: @cool you are welcome :), its better to use classes, `addClass` `removeClass` methods, instead of playing with js for css styles as i did.

Comment: I will probably use one styling again (because i dont have too much input fields where i need to implement different styling for different words. But your solution is really good and eliminates a lot of my doubts about how to implement this...tnx

Answer (score 0):

You may change the color of an input using the `color` style attribute. Having separate colors for each word is much harder. You need to have an overlay that displays the right colors. Besides, the cursor would disappear, so that the user wouldn't know where he currently is.

Comment: I see.... Yes i know its hard, expecialy becase this needs to work in all (most) browsers...tnx :)